# Android Studio & SVN - How to mark files for deletion on next commit?

Tags: svn, android-studio

I am stumped.  I'm using the SVN in Android Studio.  I've deleted some files on my working copy, and I am ready to commit the changes so they are removed from the latest revision on the repository.  I go to VCS > Commit Changes, and it doesn't make any mention of files being removed.

If I later update my project, it will redownload those from the repository.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about Android Studio, so I'm just making a guess here based on other systems.

I'd guess there is a "remove" or "delete" option in your "VCS" menu. You should use that to delete items permanently. If there is no such menu option, perhaps the SVN plugin interfaces directly with Android Studio, in which case you could just use a "remove" or "delete" menu item on the file from an Android Studio menu.

If that also fails, I assume Android Studio's SVN plugin still uses a normal .svn directory. Download the SVN command-line tools, find the directory your project is stored in, and use `svn rm` to remove your files.